# The share plugin in switchboard seems not to work in Loki

Tags: release-loki, samba

1. open switchboard.
   [image]
2. open the share plugin.
   [image]
3. As you can see, it doesn't work.
   [image]

Comment: How should you go to see access to other devices shared in my local network? In Freya I could see the shares directly from entire network

Answer (score 1):

It works perfectly, it enables DLNA server functionality, NOT Samba. :)

Comment: Do you know which port should I open for the DLNA service when the firewall is enabled?